# how to update an object in symfony 3?

Tags: ajax, symfony, symfony-3.3, symfony3.x

I want  to update profile infos, but after everything I have done nothing happened..

I work using ajax to send data from twig  to updateAction ..

ajax :

```
 $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            $("#btnEnregistrer").click(function () {

                var URL = "{{path('profile_update')}}";
                var n = $('#txtNom').val();
                var nAr = $('#txtNomAr').val();
                var pre = $('#txtPrenom').val();
                var preAr = $('#txtPrenomAr').val();
                var passOld = $('#txtPassOld').val();
                var pass1 = $('#txtPassNew').val();
                var pass2 = $('#txtPassNew2').val();
                var dateN = $('#txtDateN').val();
                var ad = $('#txtAdresse').val();
                var adAr = $('#txtAdresseAr').val();
                var mob = $('#txtMobile').val();
                var fixe = $('#txtFixe').val();

                var sexe ;
                if($('#rbHomme').is(':checked'))
                    sexe="Homme";
                else
                    if($('#rbFemme').is(':checked'))
                        sexe="Femme";

                 var DATA = 'nom='+n+'&nomAr='+nAr+'&prenom='+pre+'&prenomAr='+preAr+'&sexe='+sexe+'&passOld='+passOld+'&passNew='+pass1+'&passNew2='+pass2+'&dateN='+dateN+'&adresse='+ad+'&adresseAr='+adAr+'&mobile='+mob+'&fixe='+fixe;

                $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                    url: URL,
                    data: DATA,
                    cache: false
                });
            });

});
```

{{path('profile_update')}}    is the route of updateAction :

```
public function updateAction(Request $request)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {

        $utilisateur = $this->get('session')->get('user');

        $Vparam = $em->getRepository('ParametersBundle:Parameter')->findOneBy(['id' => $utilisateur->getVille()]);

        $utilisateur->setNom($request->get('nom'));
        $utilisateur->setNomAr($request->get('nomAr'));
        $utilisateur->setPrenom($request->get('prenom'));
        $utilisateur->setPrenomAr($request->get('prenomAr'));


        $s = $request->get('sexe');

        if($s == "Homme")
        {
            $utilisateur->setSexe("Homme");
            $utilisateur->setSexeAr("ذكر");
        }
        else
        {
            $utilisateur->setSexe("Femme");
            $utilisateur->setSexeAr("أنثى");
        }

        $utilisateur->setDateN($request->get('dateN'));
        $utilisateur->setAdresse($request->get('adresse'));
        $utilisateur->setAdresseAr($request->get('adresseAr'));


        if($request->get('passOld') !="" && $request->get('passNew') !="" && $request->get('passNew2') !="")
        {
            if($request->get('passOld') == self::getHash($utilisateur->getPassword(), $utilisateur->getSalt()))
            {
                if($request->get('passNew') == $request->get('passNew2'))
                {
                    $utilisateur->setPassword(self::getHash($request->get('passNew'), $utilisateur->getSalt()));
                }
                else
                { 
                    return $this->redirectToRoute('ens_profile');
                }
            }
            else
            {
               return $this->redirectToRoute('ens_profile');
            }
        }

        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('ens_profile');

    }
```

route.yml :

```
persons_connexion:
    path:     /connexion
    defaults: { _controller: PersonsBundle:Default:connexion }

persons_deconnexion:
    path:     /deconnexion
    defaults: { _controller: PersonsBundle:Default:deconnexion }

ens_profile:
    path:     /Enseignant/profile
    defaults: { _controller: PersonsBundle:Enseignant:profile }

profile_update:
    path:     /Enseignant/profile/miseajour
    defaults: { _controller: PersonsBundle:Enseignant:update }
```

the  parameters show up in Symfony Profiler  as POST Parameters ..
but  when I look at the table in database, I found that nothing happened ..
So, what is the problem? and how can I solve it?

Comment: Your problem is the `User` object not exist in entityManager. You have to tell your `em` here is my `User` object. Entity Manager does not knows out of his scope. ( like session )

Comment: Are you using annotation or yml for routes? If you use annotation, please update your question to include annotation above your function. I will provide an answer afterward

Comment: No, I use yml for routes

Answer (score 1):

First, you're doing something really odd...
Instead of having javascript fetch your user data in the DOM, why don't you use a form and submit it directly?

You seems rather new to Symfony, so I will suggest the best method for you to learn how Symfony does things... Use the commands lines to generate entities, controllers, forms, and so on...

Here is a list of the most user commands to work with Symfony:

***Create a bundle***
`php bin/console generate:bundle`

***Create an entity***
`php bin/console doctrine:generate:entity`

***Refresh all entities getters and setters within a bundle***
`php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities *NameBundle*`

***Refresh one entity getters and setters***
`php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities *NameBundle:Entity*`

***Check entities relations and and database squeleton***
`php bin/console d:s:v`

***Create entity form type***
`php bin/console doctrine:generate:for`

***Create entity controller, form type and view***
`php bin/console doctrine:generate:crud --with-write`

***Dump SQL changes into console.***
`php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql`
Use before updating skeleton to check if every is as you want it.

***Apply SQL changes***
`php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force`

***List all existing routes into the console.***
`php bin/console debug:router`

***Clear production cache***
`php bin/console cache:clear --no-warmup --env=prod`

***Clear developemnt cache***
`php bin/console cache:clear --no-warmup --env=dev'`

Because it make things easier, I would suggest you to use annotation for routes instead of yml.

For your code, it's a real mess and not valid as is...
If you were using a form, this is how the basic edit action should looks like

```
public function editAction(Request $request, User $user) {
    $editForm=$this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);
    $editForm->handleRequest($request);
    if($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
        $this->getDoctrine()
             ->getManager()
             ->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('_edit', array('id'=>$user->getId()));
    }

    return $this->render('security/edit.html.twig', array(
        'user'=>$user,
        'edit_form'=>$editForm->createView(),
    ));
}
```

You code is missing the form part, and is really dangerous as is...
As a good example, you don't submit any form token, which will result in a fail when you try to update database.

I'm afraid that providing help on your code it quite impossible as you're not using symfony as you should.

Comment: Yes, I'm new in symfony, but I know all thing that you have mentioned above.. Working with ajax gives you the ability to refresh data in the page without having to refresh the whole page, and this is exactly what I want .. I have done I lot of things with ajax and it works fine ..

Comment: in your example( working with symfony forms), How can I get which radio button is checked ?

Comment: I can work with html form tag .. So, I use input tag with name attribute, then I use the name to call this input in Controller ..
but I don't know what to do with inputs that are radio type, because there are more than one input has that name.. any idea? and I'm sorry! (I'm new in symfony ^_^ )

Comment: Add a class to your form, then with javascript, detect the `$.on('submit', function(e) {})` event. Within your function, start with `e.preventDefault`. Then with Ajax, submit your form with `data: $(this).serialize`

Comment: @Dev here is a short code example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wXwwKp  I return json as answer, but most likely, you want to remove the dataTypeattribute.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `$em->persist($utilisateur)` before the flush if it's not coming from your entity manager.

Comment: I read before in symfony documentation that calling $em->persist($utilisateur) isn't necessary. Recall that this method simply tells Doctrine to manage or "watch" the $utilisateur object. In this case, since you fetched the $utilisateurobject from Doctrine, it's already managed.

Comment: if you working on an existing object in entitymanager, you can't persist it. it is already persisted. you can only update it with `flush` method.

Comment: I believe this is only true for existing entities (retrieved from the database). Does `$utilisateur = $this->get('session')->get('user');` follow this rule ?

Comment: @The_Dod This is not an answer... use comments for such things.

Comment: @The_Dod during login, I save object user  in a session, so I use it  as long as it still online .. The problem here is I want to update his infos

Comment: Don't know if it's best way to do it but i'd get the user id and retrieve it from the database using $em, then apply changes to it and flush it at last. @Preciel I formatted my answer to try to match your expectations of an answer, please provide details if this is not what you meant...